# Access to Selfoss and Dettifoss in winter season

Tags: sightseeing, driving, weather-and-climate, iceland, winter

According to the [Road Condition site](http://www.vegagerdin.is/english/road-conditions-and-weather/north-east-iceland-and-the-eastern-fjords/ne_efj1.html) of the Icelandic government, roads 862 and 864 that are the closest to [Selfoss and Dettifoss](https://maps.google.es/maps?q=Selfoss,%20Nor%C3%B0urland%20Eystra,%20Islandia&hl=es&ie=UTF8&ll=65.808967,-16.374435&spn=0.096652,0.264702&sll=65.800525,-16.360703&sspn=0.193366,0.529404&oq=selfo&gl=es&hq=Selfoss,&hnear=Nor%C3%B0urland%20Eystra,%20Islandia&t=m&z=12) are "impassable" right now. This condition has been maintained for weeks, and I'm afraid that when we arrive there (in 3 weeks) the road will still have the "impassable" mark.

As we will drive a non-4×4 vehicle, is there any alternative way (by foot or public transport) to get to these sights in April?

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to get there on foot. It is more than an hour's drive from the Ring Road on 862/864.

I'm sure there are 4×4 tours you could hire, but I am not aware of a public route there.